Why does the timelike killing vector become spacelike inside the ergoregion?
Why does the timelike killing vector become spacelike inside the ergoregion?
Some textbooks make this claim and move on to explain negative energy, but I could not find any proof for this claim. I can't find how they define timelike killing vectors and  what equation indicates that once an object passes the stationary limit, the timelike killing vector becomes spacelike.
Moreover, how does frame dragging connect to the killing vector being spacelike?

It's impossible that you couldn't find a discussion of this anywhere as it is covered in pretty much all GR textbooks.
The Kerr metric is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
ds^2 = - \left( 1 - \frac{rR}{\Sigma} \right) dt^2 + \frac{\Sigma}{\Delta} dr^2 + \Sigma d\theta^2 + \left( r^2 + a^2 + \frac{r a^2 R}{\Sigma} \sin^2\theta \right) \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2 - \frac{2 r R a \sin^2 \theta}{\Sigma} dt d\phi
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Sigma = r^2 + a^2 \cos^2 \theta , \qquad \Delta = r^2 - r R + a^2 . 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The norm of the Killing vector $\partial_t$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\partial_t|^2 = g_{tt} = - 1 + \frac{rR}{\Sigma}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
This vanishes when
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
( \Sigma - r R )|_{r=r_E} = 0  \quad \implies \quad r_E = \frac{R}{2} + \sqrt{ \frac{R^2}{4} - a^2 \cos^2 \theta }  . 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
when $r > r_E$, $|\partial_t|^2 < 0$ so $\partial_t$ is a timelike vector. When $r<r_E$, $|\partial_t|^2 > 0$, so it becomes a spacelike vector.
